# Can't import .ane file into Flash CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, ane

I've been trying for days now to import an .ane file into a Flash CC project in order to use admob banners with it.

I've searched everywhere and I just can't make it work.

Here's what I'm doing exatcly:

- I downloaded the .zip file from this github: https://github.com/lilili87222/Admob-ANE
- Inside the .zip file, I got the "admob_all_in_one_6.12.2.ane" file only and put it into a "lib" folder, together with my project .fla.
- Then, inside Flash CC I open the "Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Settings" window, navigate to the "Library Path" tab and click the "Browse to Native Extention (ANE) File" button.
- I select my .ane file inside the lib folder and click ok. I try to compile the project, and I get this error:
  "The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Extension namespace is invalid"

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like your method is correct. Have you tried using a different ANE?

Answer (score 0):

"namespace is invalid", check the AppName-app.xml

```
  <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/15.0">
```

Change your Adobe AIR SDK for a newer

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but after I have updated the Air SDK, it works very well...

Follow [this step](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/enable-the-latest-air-sdk-in-flash-professional-cs55--active-11488) to update Air SDK.